# Symfony 4 и Messenger + RabbitMQ

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, symfony4

Вопрос в следующем. Пытаюсь разобраться с работой компонента Messenger в Symfony. Есть следующие классы:

ACSTask.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Message;

class ACSTask
{
    private $deviceId;
    private $hostToCheck;
    private $operation;

    public function __construct(?int $deviceId, ?string $hostToCheck, ?string $operation)
    {
        $this->deviceId = $deviceId;
        $this->hostToCheck = $hostToCheck;
        $this->operation = $operation;
    }

    public function getDeviceId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->deviceId;
    }

    public function getHostToCheck(): ?string
    {
        return $this->hostToCheck;
    }

    public function getOperation(): ?string
    {
        return $this->operation;
    }
}
```

ACSTaskHandler.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\MessageHandler;

use App\Message\ACSTask;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

class ACSTaskHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ACSTask $acsTask)
    {
        echo "Start\n";
        $process = new Process([...]);
        $process->run();
        echo "End\n";
    }
}
```

Метод контроллера:

```php
    public function testAmqp(MessageBusInterface $bus)
    {
        $device_id = 18;
        $address = "google.ru";
        $bus->dispatch(new Envelope(new ACSTask($device_id, $address, "ping"), [

        ]));
        return new JsonResponse([
            'status' => 'OK',
            'ping' => isset($ping) ? $serializer->serialize($ping, 'json') : null,
        ]);
    }
```

messenger.yaml

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            # Uncomment the following line to enable a transport named "amqp"
            amqp:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            'App\Message\ACSTask': amqp
```

Данная схема работает, но выполняет все задачи поочередно. Я так понимаю, что дело в том, что все задачи шлются в одну очередь. Мне же нужно сгруппировать задачи и добавить их в очереди, соответствующие группам. В официальной документации RabbitMQ сказано, что это можно сделать, но совсем не понимаю как это реализовать в рамках фреймворка.
[Publish/Subscribe](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-php.html)

Я впервые прибегаю к использованию к брокеру сообщений и возможно неправильно понимаю его работу. Возможно компоненты из коробки в Symfony не позволяют задавать нужные параметры из коробки. Прошу совета и помощи: как мне реализовать в рамках фреймворка вышеописанное или какую библиотеку под Symfony мне лучше использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Messenger прост и разделение очередей основана на классах

messenger.yaml

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            # Uncomment the following line to enable a transport named "amqp"
            runTaskPing: %env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%/task.ping
            runTaskTrace: %env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%/task.trace
        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            'App\Message\ACSTaskPing': runTaskPing
            'App\Message\ACSTaskTrace': runTaskTrace
```

Соответственно для каждого типа сообщений должны быть свои Message и свои Handler.  Возможны абстрактный Message и Handler в которых вся логика и почти пустые children которые нужны чисто для роутинга по группам.

Ну и вызов для сообщения будет соответствующий

```
$bus->dispatch(new ACSTaskPing($device_id, $address, "ping"))
$bus->dispatch(new ACSTaskTrace($device_id, $address, "trace"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle) или [enqueue-bundle](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-bundle). Они оба должны подойти для вашей задачи. Также вы можете использовать [приоритет](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) на выполнение в пределах одной очереди.